# Managing the menu button fail android

Tags: android, button

I am trying to manage menu button (it is a hard button on my device) My code works fine when I click on back button. When I press menu button, the activity goes background and toss message doesn't appear.

EDIT: I tryed volume up and down buttons in `onKeyDown` and worked fine. I don't understand why only menu button doesn't work. Is menu button a special button?

What is wrong here about menu button? and Is there any other method to manage menu button?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: you have to override the menu button functionality

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

       // perform your desired action here

       // return 'true' to prevent further propagation of the key event
       return true;
   }

   // let the system handle all other key events
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Again my activity went background, when I pressed menu button.

Answer (score 0):

For show Toast on menu button press you need to override function like that.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
      // Show your desired toast here....

      return true;
   } 
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Again my activity went background, when I pressed menu button.

Comment: @ffttyy does the menu button opens the menu?